# How to delay a CABasicAnimation?

Tags: ios, uikit, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I have a `CABasicAnimation` and want to start it after a delay. In UIKit I can specify delays. The `CAMediaTiming` protocol has a `timeOffset` property but I can't see an effect. My next try is to use GCD to delay it but it feels like overkill.

Comment: I would just use GCD.     ` dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        <#code to be executed on the main queue after delay#>
    });`

Comment: @BooRanger what is wrong with the `beginTime` property?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11625742/608157) should answer your question

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using the `[CAMediaTiming beginTime]` property ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/camediatiming/1427654-begintime))?

See *Customizing the Timing of an Animation* in the [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AdvancedAnimationTricks/AdvancedAnimationTricks.html).

```
CABasicAnimation *animation;
animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.3; //0.3 seconds delay
```

Comment: Just remember that it is `CACurrentMediaTime() + yourDelay`

Comment: I am not able to use this for AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool. The only thing which works is AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero. I want some delay for my animation...

Comment: add a fake "do nothing type" animation for that delay time.

Answer (score 22):

In Swift 3.0:

```
func animateYourView () {
   let myDelay = 5.0
   let scalePulseAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
   scalePulseAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + myDelay
   scalePulseAnimation.duration = 0.5
   scalePulseAnimation.repeatCount = 2.0
   scalePulseAnimation.autoreverses = true
   scalePulseAnimation.fromValue = 1.0
   scalePulseAnimation.toValue = 0.5
   myView.layer.add(scalePulseAnimation, forKey: "scale")
}
```

Where the key line for the delay is:

```
  scalePulseAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + myDelay
```